# Nested Transaction issue with UnitOfWork Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, unit-of-work

```
public void Operation01()
{
    //Some Data manipulation here.
    this.UnitOfWork.Commit();
}

public void Operation02()
{
    Operation01();

    //Some db work here

    //Some ERROR Occurs here, but operation 1 is commited.

    this.UnitOfWork.Commit();  
}
```

UnitOfWork is a private member of the class injected by framework using IOC.

I cannot remove Commit() from Operation01 because it is called as a stand alone operation sometimes in application.
I want to rollback every changes if any error occurs on Operation02().

Answer (score 1):

Push your work into separate method...

```
public void Operation01()
{
    Operation01Worker();
    this.UnitOfWork.Commit();
}

private void Operation01Worker()
{
    //Some Data manipulation here.
}

public void Operation02()
{
    Operation01Worker();

    //Some db work here

    this.UnitOfWork.Commit();  
}
```

Comment: Magic?  This is about as straightforward as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

How about something with delegates like this:

```
public void Operation01(Action doThisToo = null)
{
    //Some Data manipulation here.

    if (!doThisToo == null)
    {
        doThisToo;
    }

    this.UnitOfWork.Commit();
```

}

```
public void Operation02()
{
    Operation01(() =>
    {
        //Some db work here
    }); 
}
```

Maybe not exactly what you're after, but you get the point.